# Log4j New Version and old version in Nexus

Tags: maven, log4j, nexus

I have upgraded Log4j to 2.16.0 from 2.10.0 version and released the job in Jenkins .I can see the older version and new version while downloading from Nexus . Does it will the latest version while in build .How can I delete the older version ?Could anyone suggest on how to delete the older version .

Maven Pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>SampleService</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Service</name>
    <description>Project for Services</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <springboot.version>2.1.6.RELEASE</springboot.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <surefire-plugin.version>2.22.0</surefire-plugin.version>
        <log4j2.version>2.16.0</log4j2.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>${springboot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.16.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.16.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestone</id>
            <name>Spring Maven MILESTONE Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                    </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${springboot.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <arguments>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                        <uberJar>true</uberJar>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>toolchain-nexus</id>
            <url>${nexus.release.url}</url>
        </repository>

        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>toolchain-nexus</id>
            <url>${nexus.snapshot.url}</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

Comment: A maven repository (in particular releases) is immutable...no deleting... Apart from that you are mixing different versions of spring boot...that's an issue...Also you have defined log4j as provided and your project is packaging `jar` which means the log4j core/etc. will not packaged into your resulting jar nor before because spring boot used by default logback instead of log4j .... Why do you use the milestone repository ?

Comment: If Maven repository is immutable how can I update the log4j to 2.16.0 version .Without provided also I can see two versions in Jenkins build .Can you please suggest how to proceed on this

Comment: show the output from `mvn dependency:tree`.

Comment: The first which should being answered is: Do you really use log4j?

Comment: @ khmarbise  :Yes ,log4j is being used